# How to configure Maven in an existing project?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have been developing a JAVA Fx project for 6 months till now and I have realized that using a tool as Maven (or Gradle) will be necessary in the future. So, my question is: would be easy to use my JavaFx project (I started it as a new JavaFx project with Eclipse IDE) and import Maven in some way over that project? What will I need to do it (with Eclipse IDE or command line) in addition to the 'pom.xml' file?

Thanks!

Comment: As with everything Maven - [there's a plugin for that](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/).

Comment: Maven and JavaFX are not good friends... If you have configured your pom.xml, most IDEs have an option "Import Maven project".

Comment: Do you think that Gradle could be better option to work with JavaFX? Thanks.

Comment: Maven + JavaFX i guess netbeans IDE is good.

Comment: yes, Netbeans has a much better support for JavaFX that Eclipse or IntelliJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, i think you should make a new project (or a branch to the current project). When i done this for the first time i had a lot of problems with project folder structure and custom jars that needed to be imported. Yes, it's true, there is a plugin for eclipse. I think that you should create a maven project and try to make it work adding the code to that. (that's how i done it)